# How to run hybrid applications ionic/nativescript in the simulator ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, nativescript

Tried to run a variety of applications, including the base is generated at the project initialization nativescript, ionic (2) framework.
Compiling succeeds after xcode runs the simulator and it opens the app or I'll open it by clicking on the icon opens the icon background and hangs indefinitely, and at the end of the log is always the same error regardless of the framework:

CoreLocation: Error occurred while trying to retrieve motion state update: CMErrorDomain Code:104

This error Google, but at the moment I only found an open topic without solutions.
Could this be due to the fact that in macos virtualke and if so, how?

Comment: This is something probably with xcode, not about  frameworks
PS: hybrid is ionic as its using webview for its purposes, nativescript dont use webview for rendering but rendered ui is natives

Comment: yes they have a different approach but the error is the same outcomes.

Comment: could you post you environment info using "ionic info"? did try to "ionic platform add/remove ios"?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H62-zF8IkF7ZuHTHClyL0K7JdVkvurZE_AjpqjWHKC8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i did platform add/remove ios - this error 104 repeat.